# How to load text file into string array with only import java.io.* and no other library

Tags: java, file, output, load

Basically i added "import java.util.Scanner". but I wanted my code to work without that library and only "import java.io*" . However i want all my words (english word in the dictionary with the total of 109562 words in this case) in my text file to be inside the string array. Hence, in this case, without the scanner. how to do that?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class tester{

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{

    File f = new File("C:/Users/alienware14/Documents/words.txt");

    String [] words = new String [109562];

    readWords(f , words);



    /* 
     System.out.println("----ALL WORDS IN WORDS.TXT----");

     for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){

     System.out.println("");
     System.out.print(words[i]);

     } */
  }


  public static String [] readWords(File f ,  String [] words) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner s;
    s = new Scanner(f);

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){


      while (words[i] == null) {

        words[i] = s.next();

      }
    }

    s.close();

    return words;

  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled for "Java IO tutorial" and read something?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `java.io.FileReader` instead of a `Scanner`. Just google 'Java read file' to find an example for it (Using a Scanner for reading files is quite exotic). Though I don't really understand why you have a problem with importing a Scanner. Sounds like homework..

Answer (score 0):

Try split method
String[] words = yourtext.split(" "); //user space in split method for words